# Center web page and have overflow

Tags: html, css

I know how to center a web page with CSS, but I have no idea how to center it with an overflow of an oversized image/slider on both the left and right side. A perfect example is Square.com. The image is 1455px, but the window container is set to 1020px. But when you make the window wider,more of the image appears on the left and right, equally. I tried every version of the CSS code I can think of, but no luck. The 1020px container usually cuts off both sides of the image. So I was hoping you guys can help me out with the code that would achieve this result.

Comment: Put up a demo with the closest solution you found. Help others help you. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Have you tried `background-size:cover; background-position: 50% 50%;` on an outer full-width container?

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the `background-position : center center;` and it'll bleed off the ends.

Comment: Thank you. However I want to great a div for this section and put a jquery slider in this section, so it would not be a background image.

Comment: I think I got it. - margin-left: -217px; width: 1020px; position: absolute; overflow: visible;

Thanks!